# How to wait for forEach with rxjs and return a value?

Tags: angular, foreach, rxjs, fork-join

I'm trying to wait for the result of a `forEach()`with a `forkJoin` and send back a result. But I'm failing. What I try to do is something like that:

```
publish() {
    this.generateDownload().subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
)

generateDownload(): Observable<any> {
    let obs = [];

    this.objectlist.forEach(distance => {
        obs.push(
            this.initializeDistance(distance).pipe(map(() => {
                return ExcelExport.convertHTML2data(distance);
            }))
        );
    });

    return forkJoin(obs);
}
```

The function `initializeDistance(...)` returns an observable wheras `ExcelExport.convertHTML2data` is a "normal" function that returns an array of data.

What I'm trying now is to wait until `initializeDistance` returns a value. But what happens is that the `forEach` runs and also returns an array with results in `generateDownload`, but the array elements are equal. I could figure out that `forkJoin` doesn't wait until `initializeDistance` is finished.

But what can I do to solve my problem? 
Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: It has to wait. And does `return forkJoin(obs)` work? I believe it should be `return forkJoin(...obs)`

Comment: So you want to run `this.initializeDistance(distance)` in sequence? You can use `concat(...obs)`

Comment: @xyz something is "waiting" because it returns an array of the length from `objectlist`, but all elements have the same values. It does't wait until the  `initializeDistance () ... return ExcelExport...` is finished.

Comment: @martin this is what I need to do. The `concat(...)` returns only one value :-(

Comment: No, `concat` emit all values from all source Observables. If you want all emissions after they all complete you can use `toArray()` operator.

Comment: @martin it doesn't work for me. The array still does contain identical values

Comment: @LarsHagen can you create a stackblitz or something to demonstrate the isolated issue? Nothing stands out as wrong in your code, so I'm wondering if the issue exists in your `initializeDistance` implementation.

Comment: @LarsHagen Can you make a demo reproducing your issue?

Comment: @martin I could find the reason (see below) - I try to wait for the DOM :-( `initializeDistance` modifies the DOM and with `convertHTML2data` I try to grab a DOM element that is not finished. So the code above works fine... I just now have another problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should transform your array of data to an array of Observable and return the forkJoin of these observables.

```
generateDownload(): Observable<any> {
        const obs = this.objectlist.map(distance => {
            return this.initializeDistance(distance).pipe(map(() => {
                    return ExcelExport.convertHTML2data(distance);
                }));
        });

    return forkJoin(...obs);

    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what he's doing but in a different way.

Comment: I guess I found the "error". It the same issue I already had in the past. `initializeDistance` modifies the DOM and `ExcelExport.convertHTML2data` grabs that DOM object. In other words: `initializeDistance` is finished, but the DOM is still pending. That's why the code doesn't "block and wait". I know that I shouldn't work with the DOM in Angular but I need a formated table (unfortunately).